# IIS blocking LFTP command

Tags: php, iis-7, lftp

I'm trying to execute a LFTP command using the `system()` PHP method in a IIS 7.0 site.

```
$command = 'cmd /c lftp -c "open -u name,password -p 22 sftp://server.mylife.com ; cd test/portal/template ; put /cygdrive/c/inetpub/uploads/cata/exports/tpl_1421946484/cata.csv;"';
system($command);
```

I put it in a PHP file.
If if run it directly by the command line `php sendFile.php` it works fine.
But if I access this same php file throught a IIS 7.0 website, I got nothing and no error.

I can't understand where it comes from...!

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether this is a permissions problem? Is it that the account under which IIS hosts the website might not have access to the `/cygdrive/c/inetpub/uploads/cata/exports/tpl_1421946484/cata.csv` file?